# print entire xml data and tags in html - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

hi there i have an xml file where the xml tags are html attributes

like this

```
<query yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2014-05-14T23:07:06Z" yahoo:lang="en-US" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng">
<result>
<div class="article-text">
<p class="leading">رئيس الشباب راضي عن الموسم الحالي</p>
</div>
</result>
```

i want to print out the whole xml document (data and tags)
in html file

i trying to print out the node list
but it printed out as [node list] something like that

Comment: Perhaps `var txt = xmlString.replace(/</g,"&lt;");`

Comment: i need to convert the node list to string first , right ?
when i do this it didn't return a string